# How to prevent double booking in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to implement a database that enables customers to book an aircraft, a customer can make multiple bookings for different aircrafts,
but only one customer can book an aircraft at a time.

for e.g: A customer can book Aircraft_1D -> 12 but another customer shouldn't be able to book the same aircraft if they come under the same departure or arrival date.

I'm not even sure where to start, should I create a check constraint or a trigger?

Here is my code for the booking table;

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
Booking_ID            NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Company_ID            NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Penrhyn_Jet_Charter(Company_ID),
Customer_ID           NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Customer(Customer_ID),
Aircraft_ID           NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL REFERENCES 
Aircraft(Aircraft_ID),
Assignment_No         NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
Booking_Date          DATE         DEFAULT SYSDATE,
Charter_Cost          NUMBER(14,2) CHECK(Charter_Cost > 0),
Departure_Date        DATE         NOT NULL,
Departure_Location    CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
Arrival_Date          DATE         NOT NULL,
Arrival_Destination   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL
);
```

Any ideas or clues?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want a unique constraint on aircraft_id + date, but there are two dates: Departure_Date and Arrival_Date. One way to go about this is a second table holding the flights:

```
create table flight 
(
  aircraft_id  number(10),
  flight_date  date,
  constraint pk_flight primary key (aircraft_id, flight_date)
);
```

The table's primary key forbids two flights with the same aircraft on the same day.

Now write an insert trigger on booking that writes two entries, one for the departure date, one for the arrival date, into the flights table. It will lead to an exception when you insert a duplicate flight, no matter whether departure or arrival.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 `UNIQUE KEY` constraints, on the combinations of `Aircraft_ID,Departure_Date`  and `Aircraft_ID,Arrival_Date`

```
ALTER TABLE Booking 
ADD CONSTRAINT booking_unq1 UNIQUE (Aircraft_ID,Departure_Date);

ALTER TABLE Booking 
ADD CONSTRAINT booking_unq2 UNIQUE (Aircraft_ID,Arrival_Date);
```

Comment: This would not detect when two persons want to use the same aircraft on the same day, but one for their departure and the other for their arrival.